# UIScrollView Blur Effect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, stack, blur

A am using the brilliant StackBlur class with in my project which works fine however I am trying to create a similar effect to the Yahoo Weather App in which the image blurs according to the scroll value. I have managed to achieve it using the **scrollViewDidScroll** method however the effect is slow and laggy.

What is the best way yo resolve this? Storing the image to the Cache is the only thing I can think of.

Thanks

UPDATE

I simply created two UIImageViews one with the blur and then set the alpha to zero and increased it with the content offset off the scrollview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to blur every time when scrollViewDidScroll called. Instead, you need a blurred imageView with the final blur effect and none blurred imageView placed below the blurred one. Change view.alpha of blurred imageView from 0.0 to 1.0 will get this effect without extra cost.

Comment: simple but yet perfect. thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try [DKLiveBlur](https://github.com/kronik/DKLiveBlur) to show live effect of yahoo blur.